# verbose_name или label

Tags: django

Здравствуйте!

Где, по-вашему мнению, предпочтительнее определить подсказку к полю формы?

при создании модели с указанием параметра verbose_name:

```
models.py

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Название компании')
```

или при создании формы:

```
forms.py

class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', )
        labels = {'name': 'Название компании'}
```

Comment: В моделях. `labels` нужно использовать только тогда, когда пользователю на сайте надо отразить не такую метку, как админу в админке. А это чрезвычайно редкое явление.